# complete xmp/iptc manipulation command line tool or python wrapper? (osx)

Tags: python, macos, command-line, metadata, xmp

im searching for a complete command line tool or even better a python wrapper to manipulate and retrieve image metadata.

i tried **pyexiv2** which is very nice but i cant register a new namespace like 'XMP.imageapp.uuid' (maybe im missing something and i would be glad to hear a solution for that.)

with the command line tool **exiv2** i can't read a single value for a key. so if im searching for Xmp.dc.subject i have to get all the xmp data and grep the value. (not that nice)
with exiv2 i can register my namespace like:
exiv2 -M 'reg imageapp http://ns.imagapp.pro/imageapp/v1/' -M'set Xmp.imageapp.uuid asdfasd' 1.jpg

but then i have problems because sometimes (couldn't find when and where) it sets an xmptag 'Xmp.imageapp_1_.uuid' and i have problems deleting it because as soon as i delete it, another tag appears in form 'Xmp.imageapp_1_*1*.uuid'

i would prefer to use a python tool because my app is written in python. does anyone know how to register a new namespace with pyexiv2 or does anyone know whats best to use for my case?

thanx